# UIWindowから別のUIWindowへタッチイベントを伝搬したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

## 環境

Xcode 6.2/iOS SDK 8.2/iOS Simulator iPhone 5s(iOS 7.1), 6(iOS 8.2)

## テストコード

**註**: ストーリーボードを使わず、コードのみで画面を作成します。

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *secondWindow;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.restorationIdentifier = @"back window";
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  [self.window addGestureRecognizer: [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(didTap:)]];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  
  self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.secondWindow.restorationIdentifier = @"front window";
  self.secondWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0f green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: 0.25f];
  
  // (1)
  [self.secondWindow addGestureRecognizer: [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(didTap:)]];
  
  self.secondWindow.windowLevel = self.window.windowLevel + 1;
  self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;
  
  return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Responses

- (void)didTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
  
  NSLog(@"Did tap %@.", tap.view.restorationIdentifier);
}

@end
```

2枚のウィンドウが同じサイズで生成され、重ねて表示されています。キーウィンドウは背面のほうです。どちらのウィンドウにもタップジェスチャーの認識が組み込まれています。

## やりたいこと

このテストコードで画面をタップすると

> Did tap front window.

と出力されます。

テストコードで、(1)の行をコメントアウトして、**前面のウィンドウがイベントを処理しなくなったとき、背面のウィンドウがタッチイベントを認識するように** し、

> Did tap back window.

と出力されるようにしたいです。

## 既に分かっていること・調べたこと

- レスポンダーチェーンは最前面のビューから始まり、イベントを処理できるレスポンダが見つかるまでスーパービューを遡ってUIWindow、UIApplicationへと終着するため、ビュー階層の異なるUIWindowの位置を重ねても背面へタッチが伝搬することはない
- UIWindowがキーウィンドウであるかどうかで異なるのは、モーションイベントと遠隔操作イベントを受け取るか否かであり、タッチイベントはそれがキーウィンドウであるかに関係なく受け取る

**参考にしているリファレンスやガイド**

- [UIResponder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html) およびクラスのヘッダファイル
- [UIWindow Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html) およびクラスのヘッダファイル
- [Understanding Windows and Screens](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html)
- [iOS Developer Center 日本語ドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/) に掲載されている

  - iOSイベント処理ガイド（日本語版PDF）

## 制約・要件

- 前面のウィンドウはデバイス画面全体を覆ってください。前面のウィンドウのサイズを変更して背面のウィンドウをタップできるようにする方法は採れません（ただし、妥協案としては考えています）
- 前面のウィンドウを背面のウィンドウのサブビューにすることはできません。同じ理由で、ウィンドウを使用せず、UIViewをルートビューの最前面に貼付ける、といった別方向からの解決法は採れません
- 実使用環境ではどちらのウィンドウにもrootViewControllerがセットされ、ルートビュー以下に多くのサブビューが追加されます。テストコードでは焦点を明確にするためにウィンドウのみを扱っています

## 現在じぶんが取り組んでいる方向性

レスポンダーチェーンの流れに沿ってどのビューもイベントを処理せずにUIWindowへイベントが到着したら、ウィンドウ自身も処理をせずUIApplicationへイベントを送るところを捕まえて別のUIWindowへ送信できないか、と考えています。

**解決法のひとつとして探っているものの図解**

[image: UIWindowから別のUIWindowへイベントを伝搬]

Comment: やりたいことの図解と、参考にしているリファレンスやガイドを追記しました

Comment: 根本的なところで勘違いしています。`UITapGestureRecognizer `がイベントを処理している時点で、レスポンダチェーンは途切れています。`didTap:`はイベントではなく、ただのメソッド呼び出しです。

Comment: もちろん、UITapGestureRecognizerが処理しているときは途切れていいんです。「やりたいこと」にあるように、それ（(1)の行）をコメントアウトして誰もイベントを処理せずにレスポンダチェーンの末尾まで到達した際、他のウィンドウに同じようなタッチイベントを再送できないか、という主旨の話です。

Comment: 「前面のウィンドウがイベントを処理しない」の条件をヒットテストにしない理由って何なんでしょう？「やりたいこと」が本当に主眼なのか、それとも「イベントの転送」を実現する方法を知りたいのか、意図を汲み取れません。

Comment: やりたいことは書いてあることそのままですが・・・。ふたつのウィンドウがあり、前面のウィンドウにタッチイベントを処理するものがなにもなければ背面のウィンドウがそれを引き受ける。その解決方法が何であるかは知りません。今取り組んでいるのがイベントの転送で、妥協案として用意しているのは前面のウィンドウが不必要に背面を覆わないことです。

Comment: @quesera2 質問文の図解の意味合い（表示位置）が間違っていました。図解は「やりたいこと」ではなく、今取り組んでいる解決法のものでした。これが原因で混乱させたかもしれません。

Comment: 質問題自体が「UIWindowから別のUIWindowへタッチイベントを伝搬したい」となっているのですが、これも誤りということでしょうか？イベント処理ガイドをもう一度読んで、ヒットテストについて理解するのが良いと思います。

Comment: @quesera2 質問のタイトルは期待の動作を端的に表したものです。ヒットテストについて理解しても、ヒットテストの性質上「できない」という答えしか見つかりません。「できない」という結論しか導きだせないから他の人に質問しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** レスポンダチェーンを使う意義はほぼありません。それよりも、`UIWindow`が重なっていても、ヒットテストが正しく実装されていれば、ヒットテストビューを背面のウインドウにすることが可能です。それが一番手っ取り早いのではないでしょうか。

```
class AnotherWindow : UIWindow {
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    var hitTestView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
        return hitTestView === self ? nil : hitTestView;
    }
}
```

これは非常に単純な例です。ヒットテストの結果、「前面のウィンドウ自身が結果として取得された場合」、に`nil`に置き換え、背面のウインドウに移譲します。この実装では期待する要件に合わないかもしれません。しかし指定が非常にふわふわしているので、実現方法そのものは存在するという点についてだけ言及させて頂きます。

> ヒットテストについて理解しても、ヒットテストの性質上「できない」という答えしか見つかりません。「できない」という結論しか導きだせない

いや、そんなことはない、不可能だというのであれば、その根拠をお願いします。「**ヒットテストの性質上「できない」という答え**」がどこにあるのか、私気になります。

---

以下の古い記述は、「UIWindowから別のUIWindowへタッチイベントを伝搬したい」という質問文に対して、

- 異なる`UIWindow`間での座標変換をどうするのか
- タッチイベントは転送できたとして、そこからどう`UIView`のイベントの発火に繋げるのか
- 放棄されるイベントを回収して、再度実行するのは無限ループの可能性が高いがどのような対処を考えているのか
- 「タッチイベント」と「タップジェスチャ」の違いを認識しているのか

など突っ込みどころが多かったので、「無理ですよ」に留めた解答です。

---

「`AppDelegate`は`UIResponder`に準拠している」のですから、タッチイベントの転送はたとえば`touchesBegin()`を呼び出して終わりです。

しかし`UIApplicationDelegate`実装クラスはレスポンダチェーンの末尾にいるため、ここから別の`UIWindow`に再転送しても無限ループが発生するだけです。

**レスポンダチェーンはヒットテストビューから上位方向へしか辿りません**、別の`UIWindow`へ転送したとして、どこかのビューが反応することはありません。

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    // 省略

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.anyObject() as? UITouch {
            if(touch.window !== self.window){        
                //keyWindow座標に変換して赤い点を描く（合ってるかあまり自信ない）
                let location = touch.locationInView(nil)
                let convertedLocation = self.window!.convertPoint(location, fromWindow: touch.window)
                let pointer = UIView(frame : CGRect(origin: convertedLocation, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)))
                pointer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
                self.window!.addSubview(pointer)

                // getterしかないプロパティを書き換えるのにKVCを利用
                // 処理されないイベントが無限ループしてStackOverflowになります
                touches.setValue(self.window!, forKey: "window")
                // タッチ開始を別ウインドウに渡す
                self.window!.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: そのUIWindowやそれのサブビューに結びついたUITouchがUIEventに含まれていないため「別のUIWindowへ転送したとして、どこかのビューが反応‌​することはありません」は正しいと思います。方向性のひとつとして、その反応を起こす方法を探っています。

Comment: なるほど。じぶんは、ヒットテストはそのビュー階層でタッチされたビューを返すだけだと思っていたので、前面と背面のウィンドウは同じビュー階層にいるべき（背面のウィンドウが前面のウィンドウのサブビューであること）という制約があるのだと考えていました。単純にnilを返せばタッチイベントがいわば透過していくことを知らなかったし、求めていた回答がずばりこれです。この「hitTest:...の返り値をnilに置き換えることでイベントが透過していく」ことはじぶんの読んだリファレンス類からでは辿り着けませんでしたが、この仕様についてどこかに書かれているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず下記のようなコードでそれっぽく出来ますがどうでしょうか？
もう少しやりたいことが具体的に分かると回答し易くなります。
色とかは分かり易いものに変えています。
RootViewControllerは適当に用意してください。

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.window.restorationIdentifier = @"back window";
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:0.5f];
    [self.window addGestureRecognizer: [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(didTap:)]];
    RootViewController* vc = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.secondWindow.restorationIdentifier = @"front window";
    self.secondWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0f green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: 0.5f];

    // (1)
    [self.secondWindow addGestureRecognizer: [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(didTap:)]];

    self.secondWindow.windowLevel = self.window.windowLevel + 1;
    self.secondWindow.hidden = YES;
    self.secondWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    vc = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    self.secondWindow.rootViewController = vc;

    return YES;
}

- (void)didTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {

    NSLog(@"Did tap %@.", tap.view.restorationIdentifier);

    UIWindow* frontTargetWindow = (tap.view == self.window)?self.secondWindow:self.window;
    tap.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    tap.view.hidden = YES;
    frontTargetWindow.hidden = NO;
    frontTargetWindow.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [frontTargetWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: うーん、前面のウィンドウを非表示にしてレスポンダーチェーンから外してしまっては意味がないのですが……。「前面のウィンドウ上にタッチイベントを処理できるレスポンダが皆無なときに、背面のウィンドウへタッチイベントを伝搬させたい」で、具体的な内容が伝わりますでしょうか？